# Compiling partial documents (without document tags)

Tags: compiling, preamble

I am getting some colleagues to migrate from Word to LaTeX for technical documents, but old habits die hard.

I am looking for a way to compile each LaTeX document partially without document tags, so that each document can be previewed easily, while still being capable of inclusion in a larger document which will in fact have a document tag.

Is it possible to have document tags in all documents (read .tex files) to allow fragment compilation, then suppress them once an inclusion is performed?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "document tag"? environments? preamble? --- You might want to take a look at `standalone`.

Comment: I mean the preamble + document environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you mean the `document` environment (`\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`) and the preamble with "document tags".

Technically you need them in any compilable LaTeX document. There are some packages which allow you to ignore the preamble (incl. `{document}`) of included sub-files. A simple one is the `docmute` package. Extended features (like coping the sub-preambles to the main one) are provided by the `standalone` package and class, which however targets more the inclusion of diagrams which should be also compilable standalone, but is also suitable for sub-documents.

Simple create the other documents as normal including a `\documentclass` and `document` environment, and then load the `docmute` or `standalone` package in the main document. These redefine `\documentclass` etc. so that they are ignored.

There is also the `combine` class and accompanied packages, which might be also useful for you.

Comment: I chose the standalone package, does what I want for now.

Comment: As much for future reference as anything else, the `subfiles` package does a very similar thing to standalone by allowing you to build all of your *.tex files using the preamble and document class/parameters from the main *.tex file, and so may be considered by future viewers of this question if they don't want the document class of subfiles to default to article, which I think `standalone` does.

Comment: @Edd: Thanks for also mentioning `subfiles`. With the `standalone` class the sub-files include their own preamble so that they can be compiled standalone. The used class default to `article`, but this can be easily changed using the `class=<class>` option. The `standalone` package allows you then to copy the sub-preamble to the main preamble. Quit the opposite direction like for `subfiles`.